# Node module.exports pattern - Is this correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JS and I am currently working on an IRC bot. I have produced the following module which I want to use for creating bot commands.

```
 /***
 * Module contains available bot commands including
 * access levels to view/utilise command and help text.
 * 
 * Usage example: commands.tg.play(payload);
 * 
***/
module.exports = commands = { 
  tg: {
    reg: '^[. - !]tg',
    help: 'some help text for tg',
    play: function(payload){tg(payload);}
  },
  help: {
    reg: '^[. - !]help',
    description: 'some help text for intel',
    play: function(payload){help(payload);}
  }

};

function tg(payload){
//Example: msg_route: pm msg_from: munkee msg_data: .tg munkee testing message via tg command msg_match: .tg msg_method: .          
  console.log("msg_route:" + payload.msg_route + ' msg_from: ' + payload.msg_from + ' msg_data: ' + payload.msg_data + ' msg_match: ' + payload.msg_match + ' msg_method: ' + payload.msg_method);
  return;
}

function help(payload){
var output='Available commands: ';
  for (var i in commands){
    output=output+ ' ' + i.toString();
  }
 return console.log(output);
}
```

As you can see I am currently defining some methods within my commands object. In order to try and keep things a bit cleaner I define the functions to actually be run below the commands object. I can access these easily via commands.help.play(payload). However I wanted to know whether there is a better way to do this or is the direction I am going correct? At the moment the commands are very skeleton and will be carrying out quite a bit more work but I just wanted to post something to give the general idea.

Comment: better to look at some node modules available freely on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the extra fn call you're making: `play:function(payload){tg(payload);}` should be just `play:tg` since functions are first-order citizens in js. I do also prefer to assign to module.exports at the end of the file.

```
/***
 * Module contains available bot commands including
 * access levels to view/utilise command and help text.
 * 
 * Usage example: commands.tg.play(payload);
 * 
***/

var commands = {};

function tg(payload){
//Example: msg_route: pm msg_from: munkee msg_data: .tg munkee testing message via tg command msg_match: .tg msg_method: .          
  console.log("msg_route:" + payload.msg_route + ' msg_from: ' + payload.msg_from + ' msg_data: ' + payload.msg_data + ' msg_match: ' + payload.msg_match + ' msg_method: ' + payload.msg_method);
  return;
}

function help(payload){
var output='Available commands: ';
  for (var i in commands){
    output=output+ ' ' + i.toString();
  }
 return console.log(output);
}


// export
module.exports = commands = { 
  tg: {
    reg: '^[. - !]tg',
    help: 'some help text for tg',
    play: tg;
  },
  help: {
    reg: '^[. - !]help',
    description: 'some help text for intel',
    play: help}
  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for this Lucio. I appreciate the way I am going is not so scalable but I think for now it is what I can stick with until I gain further knowledge on best ways to implement. As long as what I am doing is not drastically incorrect for now..

Comment: yes that extra function call is not needed @munkee have a look on my answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

It is about my personal prefrence but i will go for this one. Singleton pattern with Constructor

```
 function Commands(){
    this.commands = {};
    this.tg = function (payload){
        //Example: msg_route: pm msg_from: munkee msg_data: .tg munkee testing message via tg command msg_match: .tg msg_method: .          
          console.log("msg_route:" + payload.msg_route + ' msg_from: ' + payload.msg_from + ' msg_data: ' + payload.msg_data + ' msg_match: ' + payload.msg_match + ' msg_method: ' + payload.msg_method);
          return;
        };



this.help = function (payload){
    var output='Available commands: ';
      for (var i in commands){
        output=output+ ' ' + i.toString();
      }
}
  this.commands.tg= {
    reg: '^[. - !]tg',
    help: 'some help text for tg',
    play: this.tg
  };
  this.commands.help= {
    reg: '^[. - !]help',
    description: 'some help text for intel',
    play: this.help
   };


}


if(!!obj)
obj = new Commands();

module.exports = obj;
```

Comment: The `if(!obj)` is not necessary as node.js caches required modules and does not run their code twice.

Comment: By the way, to the OP's question. This is a good way but I find it even better to have the constructor exposed by a separate module as one can then test it however they like whereas here, you can only test the one exported instance of it.

Comment: Seems to be throwing up quite a few errors A.B. might be worth running through jslint to seem them.

Comment: A.B still hitting line 1, col 20, Unmatched '{'.

Comment: perfectly working now @munkee, sorry for the syntax errors before